# How to annotate an EnumMap with an Enum as a value in hibernate?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, hibernate-annotations

I'm using Hibernate annotations in a class containing a map of properties, which are basically `<name, value>` pairs. The property names are defined in a `PROPERTY enum`, and each property has a set of permissible values, also defined as an `enum`. Since each property has its own `enum` defined for its values, the property map is defined as

```
Map<PROPERTY, Enum> properties = new EnumMap<PROPERTY, Enum> (PROPERTY.class);
```

I am having trouble mapping the `Enum` value. This definition:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@Column(name="value")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Map<PROPERTY, Enum> properties = new EnumMap<PROPERTY, Enum> (PROPERTY.class);
```

generates the following DDL:

```
create table EnumMapTest (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table EnumMapTest_properties (
    EnumMapTest_id bigint not null,
    value tinyblob,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (EnumMapTest_id, name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

As you can see, the Enum class is mapped as a `tinyblob`, which is totally unreadable in the database.

If I define the map with a concrete `enum`

```
enum VALUE {ONE, TWO, THREE};

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@Column(name="value")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Map<PROPERTY, VALUE> properties = new EnumMap<PROPERTY, VALUE> (PROPERTY.class);
```

the mapping is fine:

```
create table EnumMapTest_properties (
    EnumMapTest_id bigint not null,
    value varchar(255),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (EnumMapTest_id, name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So the issue is the mapping of the `Enum` class itself.

Is there a way to do map an Enum to something readable (preferably a string) without creating a custom type?

I hope the fact that we are still at Hibernate 3.6.10 won't be held against us.

TIA for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify any type, hibernate saves it using serialization. That's why it generates a tinyblob.

In your case, I would recommend that you make a Map of strings (`Map<PROPERTY, String>`) since you just use Enum values. You have to convert the enums to string by hand (combination of enum-class name and enum-name) but it's readable.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing; thanks. I was hoping to save the manual conversion.